# How do I set pinescript to only buy once 5% above original indicator

Tags: pine-script

I need my pinescript to only set a buy order once the indicator has been set and then rises 5% and the condition or indicator is still true.

Below is my current code what would I need to modify?
Any ideas on how to do this?
any help would be greatly apprciated

//@version=2
strategy("EMA Long Only Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

```
len = input(21, type=integer, minval=1, title="Length")

price = sma(close, 2)
average = ema(close, len)
diff = atr(len)
bull_level = average + diff
bear_level = average - diff
bull_cross = crossover(price, bull_level)
bear_cross = crossover(bear_level, price)

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=bull_cross) 
strategy.close("Buy", when=bear_cross) //strategy.entry("Sell", 
strategy.short, when=bear_cross)

plot(price, title="price", color=green, transp=50, linewidth = 4)
plot(average, title="average", color=red, transp=50, linewidth = 4)
a1 = plot(bull_level, title="bull", color=red, transp=50, linewidth = 1)
a2 = plot(bear_level, title="bear", color=red, transp=50, linewidth = 1)
fill(a2, a1, color=red, transp=95)
```

Comment: What is the "original indicator" you are talking about here?